# XPath scrape data from Table in DIV style, using classes as columns and rows - get adjacent DIV based on DIV

Tags: xpath

The page that Im trying to scrape looks like the code below.
Based on text scraped and verified from one DIV, I need to scrape value from following DIV.

I have the right XPath to get the DIV that I need to verify, however, I cannot figure out how to get the text from the adjacent DIV?

```
<h3>TableWithColumnsAndRowsDIVstyle</h3>
<div class="row row-flex rowLine" style="padding: 2px 0;">
    <div class="col-1 vcenter">
        ::before
        <h4 style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        RowValueNameX
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 vcenter text-right">
        ::before
        <h4>
            <b>RowValueX_ThatINeedToExtract</b>
        </h4>
    </div>
    ::after
</div>
<div class="row row-flex rowLine" style="padding: 2px 0;">
        <div class="col-1 vcenter">
            ::before
            <h4 style="white-space: nowrap;">
                            RowValueNameY
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 vcenter text-right">
            ::before
            <h4>
                <b>RowValueY_ThatINeedToExtract</b>
            </h4>
        </div>
        ::after
    </div>
<div class="row row-flex rowLine" style="padding: 2px 0;">
        <div class="col-1 vcenter">
            ::before
            <h4 style="white-space: nowrap;">
                            RowValueNameZ
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 vcenter text-right">
            ::before
            <h4>
                <b>RowValueZ_ThatINeedToExtract</b>
            </h4>
        </div>
        ::after
    </div>
```

The XPath that I have looks like this

```
 //*[contains(normalize-space(text()),"RowValueNameX")]
```

Now I need to get this text

```
 RowValueX_ThatINeedToExtract
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the first `div`block containing the text are looking for, you can use:

```
//div[contains(div, "RowValueNameX")]
```

This gives:

```
<div class="row row-flex rowLine" style="padding: 2px 0;">
  <div class="col-1 vcenter">
    ::before
    <h4 style="white-space: nowrap;">
      RowValueNameX
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 vcenter text-right">
    ::before
    <h4>
      <b>RowValueX_ThatINeedToExtract</b>
    </h4>
  </div>
  ::after
</div>
```

You want the second `div` child, so the complete XPath looks like this:

```
//div[contains(div, "RowValueNameX")]/div[2]
```

This results in:

```
<div class="col-2 vcenter text-right">
  ::before
  <h4>
    <b>RowValueX_ThatINeedToExtract</b>
  </h4>
</div>
```

From here it should be easy to get to the text you actually want.